# JavaScript closures and a for loop

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why the result of the following code is 0 and not 3.

```
var fn = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        return function(){
            console.log(i);
        };
    }
}();

fn();
```

Comment: Because you are returning from the loop, you break out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `return` statement forces the loop to terminate and the function to stop executing.

You can learn more about `return` statements here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement

Comment: Thanks, i overlooked it completely being too much focused on figuring out what a closure is.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a closure that's calling `console.log`. When you're doing this `return` statement you're stopping `fn()` from proceeding, it returns the first thing that needs returning and halts execution. Remove the return statement (and closure) if you want to console.log.

```
var fn = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
}();

fn();
```

*Also See:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return